# Rails single user authentication: Database or Hardcoded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I just need to protect a few pages that can edit the entries in my database.  I will only need a single "User Account" for myself.  Should I go through the trouble of creating a User model and setting "proper" user authentication up?  Or is it okay to just hard code it on the controller functions that will require protection?

For the record, I would normally never hardcode user authentication for a site.  I am only asking if it is "as secure" to hardcode since the site won't even have user accounts.  I only need to protect a handfull of pages, and am looking for the easiest/quickest way to accomplish this.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay. Just keep in mind that Basic access authentication transfers the username and the password as [cleartext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Disadvantages) unless you're using SSL (which you're probably not). So it's basically up to you to judge on risk vs. effort.

Comment: Your right, I am not using SSL.  Its just a personal site to show off some projects of mine, I created a small backend to add / edit projects easily. I don't think I need SSL for that.  Although I may buy an SSL Cert for another site of mine soon, and I may use it for this as well, I'm not sure yet.  Would it be worth while enabling SSL on this kind of site?  I have never dealt with SSL directly before. How involved is it to set up?

Comment: SSL certificates are not cheap and if you've never installed one before it also involves a lot of fumbling with the settings of your webserver - at least in my experience. In the end it's up to you. Go the safe way, take the effort or go for the simple solution and take the risk (which might be negligible in your case)